# Spring MVC Hibernate MySQL - 1 day less into the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I´m using Spring MVC Hibernate and MySQL to store some data.
Everything looks good except that I in the database the date appears one day less.
Do you have any idea why this is happening?

This is part of my code:

application.properties

```
database.driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clients?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
database.username=username
database.password=password
```

Client.java

```
@Column(name ="REG_DATE")
@XmlElement
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private LocalDate regdate;
```

JSP JSTL

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${client.regdate}" type="date" />
<form:input path="regdate"  value="${regdate}"  />
```

Comment: What is the datatype of DB column which you are saving the date in?

Comment: Hi , the datatype of the column is DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify the mysql server timezone in the application.properties with the actual timezone:

database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clients?useSSL=false&&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&**serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid**

Hope this might be useful to someone